# Why is my index not changing while removing things from this list?

Tags: python

```
def remove_middle(lst, start, end):
  i = 0
  x = start + i
  while i < end:
    lst.remove(lst[x])
    i +=1
  return lst  



print(remove_middle([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42], 1, 3))

Output:

[4,23,42]
```

So when the first item is removed (8), i is incremented to 1 and start = 2. By this logic though, 16 would be removed next since without 8 that is in the lst[2] spot. From there, 42 should be removed with i = 2, x = 3, and having 8/16 gone would put 42 in the lst[3] spot.

So are the initial indexes being retained? Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2):

Because as you add to `i`, `x` is not being changed because you didn't redefine `x` as `start + 1`:

```
def remove_middle(lst, start, end):
  i = 0
  while i < end:
    x = start + i
    lst.remove(lst[x])
    i +=1
  return lst  

print(remove_middle([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42], 1, 3))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/p.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(remove_middle([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42], 1, 3))
  File "C:/Users/Caitlin/Desktop/p.py", line 5, in remove_middle
    lst.remove(lst[x])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does what it is supposed to - remove the indexes from `start` to `end`, including both end points. Something you should note is that you have never incremented `x`, which is good because the indexes keep shifting because you are operating on the list itself, not a copy. I also advise indenting 4 spaces opposed to 2, but that really is your own choice.
Also note that you are using `remove()` in a way such that the list `[1, 1, 1, 1]` when you want to delete some index it will delete index 0 because the item matches. This can be problematic in cases like `[1, 3, 1, 3, 5]` where deleting index 2 results in an incorrect `[3, 1, 3, 5]` (should be `[1, 3, 3, 5]`)

This is what it is like:
We are deleting starting from index **1** and ending at index **5** of the list `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]`:

Set `i = 0`, `x = 1`, `lst = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]`.
Loop
 1. `i = 1`, `x = 1`, `lst = [1, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]`.
 2. `i = 2`, `x = 1`, `lst = [1, 7, 9, 11, 13]`.
 3. `i = 3`, `x = 1`, `lst = [1, 9, 11, 13]`.
 4. `i = 4`, `x = 1`, `lst = [1, 11, 13]`.
 5. `i = 5`, `x = 1`, `lst = [1, 13]`.
The loop terminates at this point because the condition is no longer true. The items that remain are in index less than 1 (`start`) and index more than 5 (`end`)

```py
def remove_middle(lst, start, end):
  lst1 = lst.copy()
  i = 0
  x = start + i
  while i < end:
    lst1.remove(lst1[x])
    i += 1
    x += 1
  return lst1

print(remove_middle([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42], 1, 3))
```

Another simple way of doing this is just deleting a slice (note that this not only returns the modified list but also deletes the items *in place*):

```py
def delete_items(lst, s=0, e=-1):
    del lst[s:e]
    return lst


>>> delete_items([4,8,15,16,23,42], 1, 3+1) 
[4, 23, 42]
```